# Harry Potter Fanfic - "Professor Potter" and the power of love magic

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction

I’m looking for a fanfic I must have read >5 years ago. It was a long novel and was part of a trilogy set without horcruxes starting from where *OotP* finished. Harry & Ginny pairing.

Some facts that I remember, I’m hoping they’re a from the same story

- Harry was ‘professor Potter’ teaching DADA whilst studying
- Harry had a toy horntail dragon that he could control with his mind to practice
- There was a doctor from st mungos called Dr Stone who healed Harry often
- There was a big focus on the power of love magic. There was a test for non verbal magic and users of love magic would score 100
- Harry was a Phoenix animagus and later in the story Luna was too.

Comment: Do you happen to remember which site you read it on?

Comment: If you visit https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info, it has more prompts to help you remember details. https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11922/how-to-ask-a-good-fanfic-story-id-question?r=SearchResults has some suggestions specifically regarding fanfic.

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like [*Harry Potter, Heir of Gryffindor*](https://www.fanfiction.net/s/1717016/1/Harry-Potter-Heir-of-Gryffindor) by Brent Barten on fanfiction.net, published in 2004. It's pretty long (47 chapters) and focuses on Harry's sixth year.

**Harry was ‘professor Potter’ teaching DADA whilst studying.**

In chapter 14, "Professor Potter", Dumbledore announces there will be 5 DADA teachers this year; guess who's the fifth?

> "Your fifth instructor - for it is not to be me," he
>   continued, "is a young wizard who has faced dangers most
>   full-grown wizards could not have handled and come through with
>   flying colors. And, I am told, both he and his partner are
>   exceptional duelers. And whether he knows it or not, he is an
>   excellent teacher who instills confidence in his pupils. He will
>   primarily be responsible for teaching one of the Tuesday eveming
>   labs. However, as time allows, he will be circulating through all of
>   the classes and labs to teach you all a new charm he and two of his
>   friends have recently developed and assist the other teachers with
>   their lessons. He needs no further introduction because most of you
>   already know him." Then, looking squarely into Harry's eyes, he
>   smiled and said, "Ladies and gentlemen, I give you Professor
>   Harry Potter."

**Harry had a toy horntail dragon that he could control with his mind to practice.**

In chapter 30, "First Hogsmeade", Harry has to pick up a toy for mind exercises, and ends up picking up a Hungarian Horntail.

> "Yes," the old man said. "He told me that you were
>   looking for a specific kind of toy, a toy that would challenge your
>   abilities and force you to think about several things at once, to
>   make all of the parts work as a whole while keeping each action
>   separate and unique." [...]
>
> Fifteen minutes later, after carefully examining the few fully
>   articulating toys in the man's shop Harry selected a half-meter long
>   model of a Hungarian Horntail - the same dragon he had faced in the
>   first task of the Tri-wizard Tournament in his fourth year - and
>   carried it up to the front of the store. The old wizard looked up
>   when he recognized Harry's selection. "Ah, a little sentimental
>   value, Mister Potter?" he asked.

The same chapter also mentions a Dr Stone from St Mungo's.

> A few minutes later, as the rest of the students were nervously
>   heading into the Great Hall for dinner, Harry was sitting on a
>   stretcher on the opposite side of the Entrance Hall with his shirt
>   off while Dr. Stone was healing a rather nasty cut on his shoulder.
>   "It's lucky for you my first job at Saint Mungo's was as a
>   General Healer, Harry," Dr. Stone was saying. "Otherwise I
>   don't know what I'd do. Do you go looking for trouble or is it
>   natural?"

---

Found with the Google query `harry potter fanfiction "dr stone" mungo -site:pinterest.*`.