# Harry Potter Fanfic - Harry is a Phoenix animagus, trained by Fawkes, Luna is an animagus too

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction

I’m looking for a fanfic I must have read pre 2013, it’s a long one and is probably is part of a series. I’ll do my best to recall details, I think the vets I remember are likely split over two parts or a sequel.

Parings:

- Harry/Ginny;
- Ron/Hermione;
- Luna/Neville

Setting: preparing to kill Voldemort (I think post *Order of the Phoenix*, without horcruxes). Sticking quite close to cannon in terms of characters.

- A big focus on power of love magic and wandless/wordless magic. There was a test that Kingsley would cast in DADA (believe he was the teacher) that gave people a power score /100 on the strength of their wandless magic.
- Harry is later a DADA professor and spends a fair bit of time in the staff room. And becomes quite good friends with Snape - not too sure about this
- Harry bonds with Fawkes and they are companions and they communicate through thought. Vaguely think there was a quote like ‘Fawkes has a wicked sense of humour’
- Harry later becomes Phoenix animagus

  - Fawkes tries to teach him to sing Phoenix song
- later in the story Luna also is able to become a
  Phoenix
- Arthur runs for minister for magic. Voting happens through a tent with two channels and voters must cast a spell at an orb which gets brighter depending on the power of the caster
- Luna (100/100 on the test) votes for Arthur her vote makes the orb extremely bright and he ends up minister for magic
- Harry Ginny get married and have a child (think it was a boy James). They move into a cottage.
- Harry becomes a Goes out at night through the bedroom window to spend time as a Phoenix
- there was tension as Harry is essentially immortal
- they don’t use wands around their son to encourage him to use wandless magic
- Harry is getting him to name colours of wooden blocks and trying to get him to change their colours
- son makes a block turn ‘BLUE!’ With wandless magic

Comment: " They move into a cottage, Harry becomes a" - a word seems to be missing :)

Comment: Love magic, scored on 100, Phoenix Animagus, Harry being a DADA teacher, make me think of the answer I provided to [Harry Potter Fanfic - “Professor Potter” and the power of love magic](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/200264/98028) but some things don't quite seem to match. Could you please take a look, tell us if it might be that one or another one altogether? :)

Comment: @Jenayah I have read through the entirety of that fic and Harry is a panther/African Lion animagus, not a phoenix. Also Luna Lovegood is a falcon animagus. Harry never has kids in that one either.

Comment: @NeoDarwin hm, previous OP may have conflated two stories then. The dragon figurine seemed pretty unique enough to match

Comment: @Jenayah That story is not a trilogy either.

Comment: There is no magical test of super verbal magic either. @Jenayah

Comment: Yes I think I may have mixed two stories . The elements of wandless / non verbal magic and moving to a cottage after Voldemort’s defeat, where Harry and Ginny bring up their children without wands were definitle parts I remember

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about the 3 books by semprini:
[Veil of Mystery](https://www.fanfiction.net/s/5386877/1/Harry-Potter-and-the-Veil-of-Mystery), Ring of Reduction, and Phoenix Intuition.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you add some details of the stories, to help searchers and avoid link rot?